# Unable to update Azure Cloud Service Extended Support via Azure Powershell Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-services

I am attempting to update Azure Cloud Service Extended Support using Azure PowerShell task in Azure DevOps Release pipeline.  I receive the follow error when using Update-AzCloudService:

**Specified api-version 2021-03-01 does not meet the minimum required api-version 2022-04-04 to set this property SlotType**

Here is the code block used in the PowerShell task:

...

```
$cloudServiceIdentity = @{
    CloudServiceName = $cloudServiceName
    Location = $location
    ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroupName 
    SubscriptionId = $subscription.Subscription.Id
}
Write-Host "-------------------------------"
Write-Host = "cloudServiceIdentity.CloudServiceName= " $cloudServiceIdentity.CloudServiceName
Write-Host = "cloudServiceIdentity.Location = " $cloudServiceIdentity.Location
Write-Host = "cloudServiceIdentity.ResourceGroupName = " $cloudServiceIdentity.ResourceGroupName
Write-Host = "cloudServiceIdentity.SubscriptionId = " $cloudServiceIdentity.SubscriptionId
Write-Host "-------------------------------"

$cloudService = @{
    Location = $location
    configurationUrl = $configSas 
    PackageUrl = $packageSas
    OSProfile = $osProfile
}
Write-Host "-------------------------------"
Write-Host = "cloudService.Location= " $location
Write-Host = "cloudService.configurationUrl = " $configSas
Write-Host = "cloudService.PackageUrl = " $packageSas
Write-Host = "cloudService.OSProfile = " $osProfile
Write-Host "-------------------------------"
Write-Host "Starting Azure CSES Update"
Update-AzCloudService -InputObject $cloudServiceIdentity -Parameter $cloudService
Write-Host "Completed Azure CSES Update"
```

...

I have confirmed that Az.CloudService is running version is 1.1.0 (latest version)

Environment info:
| Environment | Value |
|:----------- |:------|
|Azure DevOps Version|18.181.31626.1 (Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1)|
|Azure DevOps Azure PowerShell Task |Version 5|
|Azure PowerShell version options - Preferred Azure PowerShell Version| 3.1.0|
|Az.CloudService | 1.1.0|

I have been struggling with this issue for several days and cannot seem to find any information on fixing the problem.

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, could your update operation with local azure powershell succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message you shared, I suppose that you could check this comment about [api version error](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/23174#issuecomment-1186906152).
And run the command below to check the latest released api version.

```
((get-azresourceprovider -providernamespace Microsoft.Compute).resourcetypes | ?{$_.ResourceTypeName -eq "virtualmachines"}).apiversions
```

And remodify your api-version parameter in your `json` or `bicep` template.

Comment: I confirmed the cloud services template is "2022-04-04".  I would prefer not to set the api-version to a previous version just so my code will execute.  Isn't it more of an issue with the Az.CloudService module?

Answer (score 0):

The issue does appear to be related to the AzCloudService Powershell Module or the CloudService Resource by itself. When creating the resource, Azure does seem to select the 2021-03-01 API version even if you have a newer version selected in your ARM Template.

It could be that this tight versioning requirements with the way Powershell makes its queries to the resource doesn't seem to work well with the resource.

In my case, I was using the New-AzCloudService cmdlet and always encountered the issue (note, to update the CloudService resource, you may still need to use the New-AzCloudService cmdlet. If the resource exists, an update operation will be performed. If the resource doesn't exist, a new resource will be created).

I noticed though that if using Powershell, all the parameters need to be specified if using the New-AzCloudService cmdlet.

As specified here in the example Step 13:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-powershell#create-cloud-service-using-profile-objects--sas-uris

you must have to pass in the other parameters before your query will be accepted (at least this is what worked for me). -Tag was not required.

So initially I was passing in my query as follows:

```
$cloudService = New-AzCloudService ` 
    -Name “ContosoCS” ` 
    -ResourceGroupName “ContosOrg” ` 
    -Location “East US” ` 
    -PackageUrl $cspkgUrl ` 
    -ConfigurationUrl $cscfgUrl
```

because I only wanted to perform a release update and I always got the error:

**Specified api-version 2021-03-01 does not meet the minimum required api-version 2022-04-04 to set this property SlotType**

When I passed in all other parameters (I referenced the existing cloud service's parameters since I'm performing an in-place update), it got accepted.

```
$cloudService = New-AzCloudService ` 
    -Name “ContosoCS” ` 
    -ResourceGroupName “ContosOrg” ` 
    -Location “East US” ` 
    -PackageUrl $cspkgUrl ` 
    -ConfigurationUrl $cscfgUrl ` 
    -UpgradeMode 'Auto' ` 
    -RoleProfile $roleProfile ` 
    -NetworkProfile $networkProfile  ` 
    -ExtensionProfile $extensionProfile ` 
    -OSProfile $osProfile
```

Hope this helps.